# Eliminar fecha, titulo, y url al imprimir página web

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, impresión

Estoy usando el plugin **jQuery Print** para imprimir áreas específicas de una pagina web, funciona correctamente, sin embargo quisiera eliminar el titulo, la fecha, y la url del area de impresión, que se colocan automáticamente al abrir el cuadro de impresión.

A continuación una imagen con los elementos que quiero quitar del area de impresión:

[image: IMG]

He leído algunos post en ingles que dicen que no es posible, pero hice una prueba en google docs, y ahi la impresion sale sin los elementos antes mencionados.

**¿Cómo podría lograr mi objetivo?**

Comment: Ya intentaste haciendo clic en más opciones de configuración, a la hora de imprimir en Chrome? Hay sale unas opciones para el encabezado y pie de página.

Answer (score 1):

saludos... bueno lo que sucede con tu impresion no depende el jquery, como ves en otras preguntas puedes ocultar los margenes o eliminarlos mediente lo siguiente:

`@media print {
    @page { margin: 0;
     size: auto; }
}`

Pero esa fecha, titulo, y url al imprimir página web es de la configuracion de impresion que te muestro en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
adicional a esto te anexo un video para que te guies mejor: https://infixnow.com/remove-header-footer-printing-google-chrome/

Comment: Buena, me sirvio de ayuda

Answer (score -1):

Se pueden eliminar los márgenes de la página con CSS para ocultar esos textos (y agregárselos al cuerpo, si querés que la impresión salga con márgenes):

```
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 2cm; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que leas sobre `CSS`, existen formas de dar estilo a las paginas para diferentes formatos, tv, smart wacht, phone. print, etc...

Para ello debes agregar un link en tu head con la hoja de estilos que deseas ocupar para la impresión. Quedaria algo asi:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">
</head>
```

La otra forma de hacerlo es que en tu mismo archivo de css normal, hagas un `@media print` para agregar los estilos para tu impresión.

```
@media print {
    // Estilos css
    @page { margin: 0; }
}
```